# XMLDocument disposal - why doesnt it support IDisposable?

Tags: .net, xml, idisposable, using, xmldocument

The XMLDocument class would seem like an ideal candidate for supporting IDisposable because...

- it could potentially hold a lot of data.
- its a represents a possibly complex model of data.

This would allow you to use it inside a Using { ... } statement and it would be garbage collected immediately after use.

However it doesnt appear to support it.

In that case whats the best way to dispose of it?

Or doesnt it need to support IDisposable - I suppose you can just set its reference to null when you have finished with it?

Or is the key difference here that it doesnt tie up external resources such as DB connections or external files and hence doesnt require IDispoable "support"?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that disposal and garbage collection are related?

Comment: Good point. From MSDN... "The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources." and "Furthermore, the garbage collector has no knowledge of unmanaged resources such as window handles, or open files and streams." Conclusion - an XMLDocument object is a managed resource.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, actually they're not completely unrelated... implementations of IDisposable often define a custom finalizer that calls Dispose, so that the instance is disposed when it is garbage collected. But of course this behavior is not enforced by anything, so you usually can't rely on it

Comment: @Thomas, correct, they're only as related as you make them, and even then there are no guarantees when or if finalization will run. Certainly within the context of the question, they're apples and oranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is the key difference here that it doesnt tie up external resources
>   such as DB connections or external files and hence doesnt require
>   IDispoable "support"?

Yup, you've hit the nail on the head there. The only resource it uses is memory (granted potentially lots of objects to represent an XML document), and we've a perfectly cromulent facility for managing memory in .net. i.e. the garbage collector.

Answer (score 5):

> This would allow you to use it inside a Using { ... } statement and it would be garbage collected immediately after use.

No, it would be *disposed* immediately after use, not garbage collected. Disposal and garbage collection are not the same thing, although they might look similar. `Dispose` is designed to release unmanaged resources, such as DB connection, file handles, unmanaged memory, etc. Garbage collection reclaims unused managed memory.

In the case of `XmlDocument`, when no references to it remain, it becomes eligible for garbage collection, and the memory it uses will be reclaimed when needed. So you just have to release all references to the `XmlDocument` and wait for the GC to do its job. Note that you *could* force a GC cycle, but you probably shouldn't: GC is an expensive operation, and the system knows better than you when is the right time to do it.